# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - after windows update forcing tls1.0

Tags: vb.net, tls1.2

I have an application that has been working for several years, recently, after a windows update, it is failing.

In my application I have set 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

However; when I run the application the connection fails.  When I did a capture using wireshark, it shows it's failing because of TLSv1.0 and the server aborting the connection.  If I enable TLSv1 on the server side, the application is fine.

Does anyone know why the Tls12 setting would be ignored, and windows using 1.0?

`If Me.ignoreCertificate = True Then
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications
End If
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()`

Comment: There's the possibility that the default TLS system settings have been tweaked, editing the Windows registry. A System update may have restored the defaults (Ssl 3,0, Tls1.0). Post the related code. How, when the `ServicePointManager` is configured, the related `ServerValidationCallback`, and the objects used (`WebRequest/FtpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, `HttpClient` (...) All of these have specific requirements/limitations).

Comment: The targeted .Net FrameWork version is quite important, too.

Comment: I have the same problem with a simple c# function that sets the same value you do above, that since the last "patch Tuesday" (this month), has stopped working due to not actually using tls1.2. I have had to remove the security updates to get the code working again.

Comment: I've added the code being used in OP

Comment: Additionally, the target version is 4.5.2

Comment: I suppose the `AcceptAllCertifications` just returns `True`. Another requirement for secure Web services you often encounter, is that the client provides a `UserAgent` Header. If you don't have one set, try with the Firefox or Chrome headers. If it's not working anyway, can you share an `Https://` public address, so it can be tested? (Remember to prepend a `@` to the nick if you want to *ping* someone specific)

Comment: Same issue - windows update was made now application code has stopped working. Also have ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 set.